# Can't connect to sql server managed instance from azure databricks

Tags: scala, azure, jdbc, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to connect to an Azure Sql managed instance from databricks. I am using Scala to connect to it. The code I have copied from the [Microsoft web site](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html)

My actual scala code : (I have changed the credentials and IP. But I have made sure they are correct as I have copied them from the connection strings in the sql server managed instance options)

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
val jdbcHostname = "dev-migdb.nf53e3653n43.database.windows.net"
val jdbcPort = 1433
val jdbcDatabase = "MYDB"

// Create the JDBC URL without passing in the user and password parameters.
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort};database=${jdbcDatabase};loginTimeout=90"

// Create a Properties() object to hold the parameters.
import java.util.Properties
val connectionProperties = new Properties()

connectionProperties.put("user", "db-devmigmgd")
connectionProperties.put("password", "pwd##321232123")

val driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver", driverClass)

val employees_table = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "employees", connectionProperties)
0
```

Error :

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host dev-migdb.nf53e3653n43.database.windows.net, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:227)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:284)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2435)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:635)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2010)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1687)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1528)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:866)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:569)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:301)
    at linee84eb162c20345fc84ad591cfefe930f29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-999597493877319:49)
    at linee84eb162c20345fc84ad591cfefe930f29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-999597493877319:104)
```

On the other hand :

1. I am able to connect to the same managed instance from the VM that is there on the same Azure subscription (using SSMS)
2. My custom application that is written in .Net and hosted on that VM is also able to connect to the same instance

**Also, I am unable to connect to the same instance from scala code that I am executing using spark shell on the above VM. BUT the errors that I am getting are different. Please find errors below.**

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'db-devmigmgd@dev-migdb'.
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2529)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1905)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1893)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4874)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1045)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:238)
  ... 76 elided
```

Comment: Is your vm vnet attached to a vnet connected to the managed instance? Can you connect to the managed instance from outside azure such as your desktop?

Comment: Is the value of  `jdbcHostname` correct in your code?

Comment: yes everything is correct. contacted microsoft support and then tried by creating a new SQL database(not a managed instance) . the connection succeeded with the same code. so basically some issue in connectivity exists with the managed instance only. Although, now I think I should debug along the lines that @simon_dmorias has suggested until managed instance team tells me what the issue is.

Comment: The reason I asked about vnet attached services working is because they can be whitelisted in MI to access it. Databricks cannot be whitelisted, so if you have enabled the firewall on MI you need to allow all Azure public IP's for that Region through. A workaround is to join the Databricks vnet attach preview: https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject.html

Comment: @simon_dmorias  yes different VNET was indeed the problem. You want to go ahead and post it as an answer or should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @simon_dmorias,

As per your comments and discussions with the Microsoft team, resources on different VNET was the real problem.

So as a best practice, always create resources in the same VNETs.